# Where "include files from the App_data folder" option?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, publishing, app-data

According this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1570909/240564), it should be option "include files from the App_data folder" when you publish ASP.NET application. But I don't see it:
[image]

Where it is?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I don't believe that option is in the newest of Visual Studio.

Instead, you should be able to change the Build Action to "Content" by right-clicking on the files in Solution Explorer and clicking "Properties."

This should then include them in the publishing process.

Comment: it isn't newest, it's VS 2010. Okay, I clicked right button -> Properties, but don't see Build Action. I see only Folder Name.

Comment: It's the newest version of Web Deploy.  If you right-click on "App_Data," then you will only see Folder Name.  You have to right-click on the individual files that you want to include.

Comment: Hi Nate, If there are no files to include and still i want to include App_Data folder during the publish, what is the option i m left with?

Answer (score 2):

I used a After Build Target. To just create a empty folder on deploy.

Add this to the end of The project file .csproj

```
<Target Name="CreateDirectories" AfterTargets="GatherAllFilesToPublish">   
    <MakeDir Directories="$(OutputPath)App_Data\"/>  
</Target>
```

Comment: Which file are you adding this to?

Answer (score 1):

1. Manually Create the App_Data folder under the published application's root folder
2. Right click at the App_Data folder and select **Publish App_Data folder**.
3. Add an item  into the App_Data folder and set the item to be include in the publish.

https://forums.asp.net/t/2126248.aspx?App_Data+folder+missing+in+release